How do I use Material Design 3’s contrast functionality from the output of material color utilities (typescript version)?
I’m getting 29 fixed colors and 6 palettes for primary, secondary, tertiary, neutral, neutral-variant and error from the typescript package of material color utilities.
Material Design 3’s color system describes the use case for applying different contrast levels. How do I programmatically in Typescript generate and use the theme for the default, medium and high contrast levels controlled by the user?
Is there a way to automatically control the contrast levels controlled - if yes, which function does that?
